# How to get response from a post request

Tags: angular, post

I am new to web development. I am trying to implement a post request to post the data recieve response. I am using ngx-uploader package. It has a post method to post the data. But i am not sure how i can get response from the server. How can i make a POST request so that i can recieve a response. please guide me.

app.component.ts

```
startUpload(): void {
    const event: UploadInput = {
      type: 'uploadAll',
      url: this.url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: { foo: 'bar' },
    };

    this.uploadInput.emit(event);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "uploadAll" as upload input type, then I am assuming you have a local files list (eg. this.files = [])

So in your app.component.ts you can add this as handler to your file upload:

```
onUploadOutput(output: UploadOutput): void {
    switch (output.type) {
      case 'allAddedToQueue':
        // uncomment this if you want to auto upload files when added
        // const event: UploadInput = {
        //   type: 'uploadAll',
        //   url: '/upload',
        //   method: 'POST',
        //   data: { foo: 'bar' }
        // };
        // this.uploadInput.emit(event);
        break;
      case 'addedToQueue':
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          this.files.push(output.file);
        }
        break;
      case 'uploading':
        if (typeof output.file !== 'undefined') {
          // update current data in files array for uploading file
          const index = this.files.findIndex(file => typeof output.file !== 'undefined' && file.id === output.file.id);
          this.files[index] = output.file;
        }
        break;
      case 'removed':
        // remove file from array when removed
        this.files = this.files.filter((file: UploadFile) => file !== output.file);
        break;
      case 'dragOver':
        this.dragOver = true;
        break;
      case 'dragOut':
      case 'drop':
        this.dragOver = false;
        break;
      case 'done':
        // The file is downloaded
        this.files.forEach(file => {
          console.log(file.response);
        });
        break;
    }
  }
```

the onUploadOutput handles the output of your file upload, as you can see there are different cases in which you can handle, so on your question - you would want to handle it on the case "done". And see the response for each of the file.

You can see a full working example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-uploader).

Also make sure your component html binds your methods correctly. Like in the documentation example:

```
<div
  class="drop-container"
  ngFileDrop
  [options]="options"
  (uploadOutput)="onUploadOutput($event)"
  [uploadInput]="uploadInput"
  [ngClass]="{ 'is-drop-over': dragOver }"
>
  <h1>Drag &amp; Drop</h1>
</div>
 
<label class="upload-button">
  <input
    type="file"
    ngFileSelect
    [options]="options"
    (uploadOutput)="onUploadOutput($event)"
    [uploadInput]="uploadInput"
    multiple
  />
  or choose file(s)
</label>
 
<button type="button" class="start-upload-btn" (click)="startUpload()">
  Start Upload
</button>
```